# ggplot2: stat_summary throws error when trying to pass function argument as parameter, rather than hard-coding

Tags: r, ggplot2, parameter-passing

I'm getting an error when I try to pass a parameter into the `round` function within `stat_summary` (even though the analogous code works with, say, `geom_text`). Here's an example:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(5)
dat = data.frame(group=rep(c("A","B"),each=10), val=rnorm(20))
```

We'll try to set the number of decimal places for value labels using a parameter, rather than hard-coding it:

```
places = 2

ggplot(dat, aes(group, val)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="text", aes(label=round(..y.., places)))
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'places' not found

The following two examples work fine, however.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(group, val)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="text", aes(label=round(..y.., 2)))

ggplot(dat, aes(group, val)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(val, places)))
```

I ran into this problem while trying to write a ggplot function. At first I thought the problem involved ggplot not getting the parameter from the function environment, but the example above suggests that's not the issue. For completeness, below is a simplified example of the function, along with the error message. The function works fine if I hard-code the digits argument to `round`, rather than trying to pass the `places` parameter.

```
pp1 = function(data, group, var, places=2, e=1.5) {

  ggplot(data, aes_string(group, var)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="text", aes(label=round(..y.., places))) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = e * range(data[,var]))

}

pp1(dat, "group","val")
```

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'places' not found

I'm hoping to find out whether I'm doing something wrong and how I can get the desired behavior.

I'm running `R` 3.2.3 and `ggplot2` 2.1.0 on OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: It looks like an NSE issue. You can dodge it by calling `eval(substitute( ...ggplot code... , list(places = places)))`, though there may be a better way.

Comment: That works. Please add it as an answer. Do you know why it's happening inside `stat_summary` and not in other places?

Comment: I'm not sure; it's something about how the NSE in `aes` works. Maybe it gets switched on by `..y..`? There is a SE version called `aes_`, but I'm not sure how to get the `..y..` argument to work in it. I'll post an answer with the above and anything else I figure out in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aes` uses [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), and will thus try to evaluate `places` within the `data` argument you give it. Its NSE varies, though, depending on what you pass it.

The typical way to bypass NSE is with `substitute`, which, well, substitutes a value inside of code. You can then use `eval` to run the code:

```
eval(substitute(ggplot(dat, aes(group, val)) +
                  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="text", aes(label=round(..y.., places))), 
                list(places = places)))
```

which works as expected:

[image: plot with labels]

Hadley also provides several SE versions of `aes`: `aes_`, `aes_q`, and `aes_string`, which may let you avoid the use of `substitute`, but which I couldn't get to evaluate `..y..`. (If anyone knows how to structure it, comment and I'll update.)

Hadley also created the [lazyeval package](https://github.com/hadley/lazyeval), which is useful for managing NSE.